# Why is it that Volunteer Army Necklace consists of two tags?

Tags: hai-to-gensou-no-grimgar

In Hai to Gensou no Grimgar the volunteer army necklace has two tags. During the fight between Mary's former party and Death Spot, and later during the fight between Death Spot and Haruhiko, all of them pulled one of the tags off from the necklace and let it fall to the dungeon's floor. Why is that? What's the point in leaving the tag there? Does the light novel, the anime is based on, explains why they do such thing? Considering that the tags doesn't come cheaply.

Comment: I was in the military once and we received [Dog tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_tag), these things tell whoever collects our body to know who we are even if our body is charred and damaged. The reason we rip it off and hand it to our comrades is to notify our family that we are dead and the corpse is not recoverable, thus please just build an empty grave. Or in Grimgar's case, it is most likely to get someone to get rid of their zombie corpse or at least tell them who the zombies are by leaving behind information that they are dead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the volunteer army necklace can be likened to the [Dog tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_tag) of our world, as a proof of identity in case of death.

In our world, dog tags are used to identify who the corpse belonged to and we receive two sets of these things. Two plates hang on our necks and 1 plate each on our ankles. In the scenario that we are unable to get our corpse back to our families, we were ordered to rip off one of the tags on our necks and hand them to our comrades if necessary. It is also used to identify mutilated corpses.

In the case of Grimgar, it most likely has the same effect. Since when they die, they become zombies, they would need to use other methods to notify their team mates they are dead. Simply leaving one of the tags there seem to be the method they opted for. Another reason is most likely to tell them who the zombies they encounter are and if possible, please get them purifed.